# About the Bessel function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was looking at this [Bessel function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), we got these two sums

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^n\frac{{4n \choose 2n}{2n \choose n}}{[(2n-1)!!]^2}=\cos\left(\frac{4}{x}\right)J_0\left(\frac{4}{x}\right)\tag1$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^n\frac{H_{n,k}}{(n!)^2}=\zeta(k)J_0\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\tag2$$

Where [$H_{n,k}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) and [$\zeta(k)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

**Just out of curiosity.**

**How does one show that the sums are correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About $(2)$: we may replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{x}$, then consider the Laplace transform of both sides.
 The problem boils down to showing

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}^{(k)}}{s^{2n+1}} = \frac{\zeta(k)}{\sqrt{4+s^2}} $$
where
$$ H_n^{(k)}=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m^k}=\zeta(k)-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{k-1}e^{-nz}}{(k-1)!}\cdot\frac{dz}{e^z-1}$$
allows to state the previous (conjectural) identity as
$$ \frac{\zeta(k)}{\sqrt{4+s^2}}-\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{k-1}}{(e^z-1)\sqrt{s^2+4 e^{-z}}}\,dz} = \frac{\zeta(k)}{\sqrt{4+s^2}} $$
or in the form: the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ integral is constantly zero for any $s$. This is not true, since the blue integral is a decreasing function with respect to the parameter $s$. In particular $(2)$ **is not** correct.

$(1)$ is correct: it is enough to consider the Cauchy product between the Maclaurin series of $\cos(4x)$ and $J_0(4x)$.